# Where is the puppet schedule state stored

Tags: puppet

I am trying to debug an issue related to a resource that is based on a [schedule](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.0/type.html#schedule).  My schedule limits this resource to only apply once a day.  I could temporarily change the schedule, but I wish to avoid that.

Is there some file on the puppet client what I can delete/truncate/modify so that it will act as if it hasn't been run during that day (or some other time period)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trick the schedule tracker by manipulating (or truncating) `/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml`.